# C Programming: Loop function which assigns to array

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops

I have the following function in C which takes an integer as input (for example, the number 1000), splits the number into individual digits (so 1, 0, 0, 0 in this case) and assigns each digit to an array called digits:

```
int splitnumber(int x)
{
    temp=x;

    while(temp)
    {
        temp=temp/10;
        factor = factor*10;
    }

    while (factor>1)
    {
        factor = factor / 10;
        digits[i]= x/factor;
        x = x % factor;
       i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

This works great the first time but if I use it in a loop, it seems the digits array is not changing each time, it still holds the same values as the first time. Same goes for when I just simply try to use the function again with a new number, it still hangs onto the result from the first try. Here is the loop I'm trying to use it in:

```
do
{
    splitnumber(number);

    lowhigh = sort_lowtohigh(digits);
    highlow = sort_hightolow(digits);

    printf ("\n\nLoop number is:%d\n", number);
    printf ("High to Low is: %d\n", highlow);

    printf ("Low to high is: %d", lowhigh);

    printf("\n");

    printf ("Subtraction is: %d", subtraction(highlow, lowhigh));

    number++;
} while (number <= 1020);
```

As you can see, I'm using a couple of other functions as well which uses the digits array. These functions seem to work fine but are not producing the correct result the second time through the loop as the digits array is not changing. Here's the output:

```
Loop number is:1001
High to Low is: 1100
Low to high is: 11
Subtraction is: 1089

Loop number is:1002
High to Low is: 1100
Low to high is: 11
Subtraction is: 1089

Loop number is:1003
High to Low is: 1100
Low to high is: 11
Subtraction is: 1089
```

The loop is incrementing the number counter but, again, the digits array is not being updated.

Comment: Where is the `digits` array declared? And where is it cleared?

Comment: Where are `factor` and `i` initialized? Please always post the **actual code** you run, including all declarations/definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems in your code (that may cause the described behavior):

In your function "splitnumber(int x)":

- You have no local variables (temp, i, factor)
- "i" is never initialized!
- no return value

I believe, the variable i (probably declared globally) causes your problem. Each time you call "splitnumber", i will be incremented. During the first call of splitnumber, i is probably 0 and will grow during that call to 3. This will affect the first 4 entries in digits (which is probably again globally declared as int[4]). When you call splitnumber the second time, i is still 4. So this time you change the values of digit[4 5 6 and 7].

If my guess is right, you're lucky that your program doesn't crash due to segmentation fault. You're trying to access memory (everything with digit[i]; i > 3) you've never allocated.

Just adding a

```
i = 0;
```

in the beginning of splitnumber will fix your problem. Using local variables in your function will may fix further problems.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, i = 0 was declared globally. Moving it inside  the function fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Since `i` is not initialized to `0` in `splitnumber`, you will only set each element of `digits` once... subsequent calls will exceed the bounds of the array.